# How to repeat only a certain element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Assuming a list as follows:

```
article = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and a variable named `times`

Now, based on the value of the variable `times`, I want to repeat just the element `'a'` in the `article` list that many times.

**For example:**

If `times = 2`,

the **desired output** is

```
article = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Similarly, if `times = 3`,

the **desired output** is

```
article = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I tried doing:

```
[['a']*times, 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

But it gives me a list within a list as follows:

```
[['a', 'a'], 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you have several `a` in the list? Can `a` be in the middle of the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `+` for join lists:

```
['a']*times + ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

In numpy is possible use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
article = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
times = 3
b = np.concatenate([np.repeat(['a'], times), ['b', 'c', 'd']]).tolist()
print(b)
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to your approach, you could [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the inner list with:

```
times = 2

[*['a']*times, 'b', 'c', 'd']
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use slicing and list concatenation for this as well:

```
>>> article[:1] * 2 + article[1:]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

`[:1]` slices up until but not including the 1st index. `[1:]` slices everything and including the 1st index.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice function you can use if the `article` and `times` variables are already defined (or they come from a function you don't want to change). This also has the advantage that the element you want to repeat can be in an arbitrary index:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def repeat_idx(ls: List[T], x: int, i: int) -> List[T]:
    """Return a new list with the element in the given index repeated x times.

    Args:
        ls: The list which element to repeat.
        x: How many times to repeat the element.
        i: The index of the element to repeat.

    """
    return ls[:i] + [ls[i]]*x + ls[i + 1:]


article = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
times = 3

print(repeat_idx(article, times, 0))
print(repeat_idx(article, times, 1))
print(repeat_idx(article, times, 3))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
> ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop here:

```
times = 3
index = 2
l = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(times):
    l.insert(index,l[index])

print(l)
```

The 'index' variable is the index of the element which you want to repeat.